# configs for several sites in apache with ssl

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, virtualization

i need to secure two different sites in apache. One of them should only be a proxy for a different server which is running on port 8069.

Now one (which is natively included in apache) runs with SSL:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName 192.168.1.20
      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/erp/oeserver.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/erp/oeserver.key
      DocumentRoot /var/www/cloud
      ServerPath /cloud/
      #CustomLog /var/www/logs/ssl-access_log combined
      #ErrorLog /var/www/logs/ssl-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

The other one is not running and even not registered. When i try to access it, i get an exception (ssl_error_rx_record_too_long):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName 192.168.1.20
ServerPath /erp/

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/erp/oeserver.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/erp/oeserver.key

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyVia On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8069/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8069
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8069/$1 [P]


RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" "https"

SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
</VirtualHost>
```

My whish is the following configuration:

```
192.168.1.20        ->> unsecured local path to website
192.168.1.20/cloud/ ->> secured local documentpath from cloud
192.168.1.20/erp/   ->> secured proxy on port 80 for http://192.168.1.20:8069
```

how is this possible? is this even possible? perhaps cloud.192.168.1.20 and erp.192.168.1.20 is better?!

Thank you
============ EDIT ==========================
apache2ctl -S -M: 
    *:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
             default server myserver (/etc/apache2/conf.d/cloud.conf:1)
             port 443 namevhost myserver (/etc/apache2/conf.d/cloud.conf:1)
    *:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
             default server myserver (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default:1)
             port 80 namevhost myserver (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default:1)

default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Modified (current) cloud.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/openerp/oeserver.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/openerp/oeserver.key
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} ^/cloud$
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8069/$1 [P]
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" "https"
    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot have

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName 192.168.1.20
      SSLEngine on
```

2 times because apache will bind to one virtualhost only.

why not include both /locations/ into one config?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName 192.168.1.20
      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/erp/oeserver.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/erp/oeserver.key
      DocumentRoot /var/www/cloud
      <Directory /var/www/cloud>
          blah
      </Directory>

      # erp-config
      # ... proxy_config ....
      ProxyPass /erp http://127.0.0.1:8069/
      proxyPassReverse /erp http://127.0.0.1:8069/

</VirtualHost>
```

---

Edit2

another way would be 2 separate `<VirtualHosts>` - configs, either Name-Based (one IP, SNI must be available) or IP-Based (one IP for each host, works usually always)

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a try. Thanks for the hint - i didn't know that this is possible

Comment: unfortunately i can not include a proxy within a <location>. Do you have other tips?

Comment: see my edit /changed  erp-config

Comment: hmmm.. it seems to work a bit better. Now I get the correct URL but the false content... the content is now the content from 127.0.0.1/ without any ssl and not from :8069.

Comment: see edit 2. for your problem: you seem to have another config flying around then? you can check with `apache2ctl  -S -M` (`apachectl` @ centos, iirc)

Comment: i added all config files. https://myIP does now secure the erp system but i cannot access the cloud. But it seems that the light at the end of the tunnel is visible :)

Comment: you're missing a `ProxyPass /erp http://127.0.0.1:8069/` - directive. your cloud-stuff should be defined and accessible from withing a `<Location>` - context

Comment: The proxyPass directive does not change anything. i still can not access the different things through /erp or /cloud. How can i define the cloud stuff in the <location> context?

Comment: when skipping locations, you might use `<Directory /var/www/cloud>`. proxy_pass should work, or you have some different config taking actions. put a different access_log into each `<Virtualhost>` and check after some requests, which one has the most recent entry.

Comment: I think it can be possible if i exclude everything with /cloud/ in the URL. RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} ^/cloud$ does not work too. How can i exclude /cloud/.... from the rewrite?

Comment: there's something fishy in your config, please adjust that first.

Comment: In the end i am using two different ports now. I guess that something is wrong with my config too. The ERP systems does a lot of ajax requests and redirects and it didnt work with the other hints. Thank you very much for your patience.